# How can I train a decision tree constrained to have number of decision nodes = tree depth?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, decision-trees

In order to make a classifier dead easy to understand/interpret, I want to classify tabular data (with `n` columns) according to a set of nested rules, with the constraint that the number of decision nodes is equal to the depth of the tree. Given a vector `x` with `n` components, the classification logic will thus look like:

```py
def classify(x):
  if x[0] < t_0:
    if x[1] < t_1:
      if x[2] < t_2:
        if x[3] < t_3:
          ...
            if x[m-1] < t_m_minus_1:
                return a_m_minus_1
            else:
                return a_m_minus_2
          ...
        else:
          return a_3
      else:
        return a_2 
    else:
      return a_1
  else:
    return a_0
```

with `m <= n`, so that the none of `else` statements can contain an `if` statement nested in it. As a consequence the number `m` of decision nodes will be equal to the depth of the tree.

Graphically (in the case `m = 3`), this will look like:

[image: Constrained tree]

A Sankey diagram can also help visualize this:

[image: Sankey]

Incidentally, I would like to use this classifier as a multi-class classifier (so not necessarily binary).

Also, ideally I'd like "else" leaf nodes to have very low Gini impurity index. Each node should be split according to a condition on a single feature only.

Is there a way to train a decision tree in scikit-learn while enforcing this constraint? What could be another library/approach to optimize such a classifier? (I would avoid coding a greedy algorithm from scratch if that's reinventing the wheel).

Comment: You could set the max depth to the desired value, then greedily trim an entire branch off each level.

Comment: This is a strange constraint: why not a complete tree then? How do you decide that the branch x[1]>0.5 should be a single node, for example? Normally it could be split again. Same  for x[2]>0.5, x[3]>0.5. The tree that you show always favours the case <=0.5: it develops a new branch for it but never for the case >0.5.

Comment: @Erwan I know it's a strange contraint, but... that's a requirement. In a way, I am forced to use this kind of "crippled" decision tree (quite less expressive than a "normal" tree).

Comment: Would you want to always keep the "biggest" (by number of samples) side as the main trunk, and the smaller one as a side branch?

Comment: Could you be allowed to have a compound conditional (at least with multiple features, single split point) for each decision level? That could bring back some expressivity

Comment: @JonNordby I tried to rephrase the question to clarify. While having most of the samples on the main trunk could be happening, what I care about is having low Gini impurity in my "else" leaf nodes. Also, I need to stick to splitting based on single features at the time :/

Comment: I think this could be solved by iteratively constructing DecisionTrees with max_depth=1, and shrinking the training set to the main trunk for each iteration. One would then construct a single DecisionTree from these separate trees, for use during inference.

Comment: @DavideFiocco Could you provide some example data (possibly constucted / synthetic)?

Comment: @JonNordby I think one could use for this something like https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_wine.html#sklearn.datasets.load_wine

Comment: Kind of a hack way to achieve what you want, but for a constant max_depth you could set max_features=1, max_leaf_nodes = max_depth and discard all trees that don't reach max_depth. If you want shorter trees as well, repeat this procedure with max_depth decreasing until 2 (or conversely, always use trees with max_depth 2 and train on the subpopulations obtained each time, then glue the trees to each other). Edit: just noticed this is what @Jon Nordby suggested.

Comment: After attempting to code it up myself, and finding that gluing the trees together in sklearn is quite tricky because the DecsionTreeClassifier code is largely in Cython, I found an implementation in an exiting library. See the added answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure you want seems to be expressable with an ordered series of if, else if, ... statements. This is a common structure for interpretable models, often called a *Rule List*, or *Decision List*. It is discussed in chapter ["Rules" in the book *Interpretable Machine Learning*](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/rules.html)  by Christoph Molnar.

There are several Python libraries that implements learning of a Rule List.

The [imodels](https://github.com/csinva/imodels) library in the submodule [imodels.rule_list](https://csinva.io/imodels/rule_list/index.html) implements many methods that can produce Rule List models, such as Optimal rule list (CORELS), Bayesian rule list, Greedy rule list and OneR rule list.

The GreedyRuleListClassifier is probably the closest to your intent, the authors call it "like a decision tree that only ever splits going left".

OneR only considers one feature in total, which is an additional restriction.

The Optimal Rule list and Bayesian rule lists requires discretizing continuous features. This can for example be done using quantile binning, or another model to find relevant/candidate breakpoints. So it is considerably more involved, but may lead to better decision lists, especially if using the probabilistic outputs.

Example code for a `GreedyRuleListClassifier` may go as follows:

```py
import pandas
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from imodels import GreedyRuleListClassifier

X, Y = sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer(as_frame=True, return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=4)

# NOTE: fitting sometimes fails with an Exception, or gives model with very bad performance
# Should attempt multiple fits and keep the best one, as estimated per a validation set
model = GreedyRuleListClassifier(max_depth=10)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, feature_names=X_train.columns)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
score = accuracy_score(y_test.values,y_pred)
print('Accuracy:\n', score)

print('Rule list:\n')
print(model)
```

Should output something like

```
Accuracy:
 0.631578947368421
Rule list:

mean 0.603 (398 pts)
if worst area >= 869.3 then 0.908 (262 pts)
mean 0.015 (136 pts)
if worst texture >= 16.67 then 1.0 (1 pts)
mean 0.007 (135 pts)
if area error >= 22.18 then 0.2 (5 pts)
mean 0 (130 pts)
```

Here is a quick attempt at visualizing this with a Sankey diagram.

```py
def plot_decision_rules_sankey(ax, rules):
    # https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/sankey_api.html
    # TODO: read the arguments
    

    from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey

    def format_rule(r):
        op = '>='
        s = f"{r['col']}\n {op} {r['cutoff']}\np={r['val_right']:.2f}"
        return s
    
    df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(model.rules_)
    print(df)
    df = df.dropna()
    df['label'] = df.apply(format_rule, axis=1)
    df['orientation'] = [1] * len(df)
    df['out'] = df['num_pts'] / df['num_pts'].sum()

    p = Sankey(ax=ax,
       margin=0.0,
       format='',
       flows=[0.0] + list(df['out'] * -1),
       labels=['Input'] + list(df['label']),
       orientations=[0] + list(df['orientation']),
    ).finish()

    ax.axis('off')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 6))
plot_decision_rules_sankey(ax, model.rules_)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('decision-rules-sankey.png')
```

[image: Sankey diagram]

Comment: The imodels library seems to indicate that multiclass is supported. But when trying it out, I do not see it working =/ only get class 0/1

Comment: imodels is great, but the instability/fragility of the method is surprising to me... I have opened an issue using your code @Jon here: https://github.com/csinva/imodels/issues/145

Comment: It was quite surprising to me as well... Thank you for filing an issue! Will follow there

Comment: Behavior was fixed in the new version of `imodels=1.3.17`.